# Time Availability Mysql Query Check

Tags: mysql

My Table structure is this..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pec_mssgs` (
      `id` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `uid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `start_timestamp` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `end_timestamp` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `text` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

Here only two fields are important that are which stores timestamp,
**start_timestamp**  and   **end_timestamp**

So the booking conditions are like.

There are two cars for hiring.

So user can insert date and time for booking cars.

So at a time there are two slots can be available for booking.

If somebody booked a car from **10:00** to **13:00** and another user can booked a car from **12:00** to **13:00** as there are two cars for booking.

So the problem is if a user wants to book a cab from **10:00** to **11:00** then it can also be possible as only one car is already booked between these period so it has to be booked.

So i want a single query which can find out how many booking are there in our db between a given time slot entered by user.

Comment: Is there a reason you are storing your times in VARCHAR format and not one of the native MySQL DATE/TIME types?

Comment: why not use `timestamp` or `datetime` datatype to store date and time? why varchar?

Comment: yes i store it in timestamp that is not a matter do whatever you want with the type i just need a query which can find out rows between two time slots.

Answer (score -1):

Is it just `select * from pec_mssgs where start_timestamp <= '11:00:00' and end_timestaml >= '11:30:00'` or I misunderstood your requirements?

Comment: @pravat231 So could you clarify those conditions?